# Bulk import 0 Rows affected

Tags: sql-server-2008, import, bulkinsert, bcp

When using the bulk insert command in SQL Server 2008 it returns:

```
(0 row(s) affected)
```

I am using this command to carry out the bulk insert:

```
BULK INSERT Test
    FROM 'C:\DataFiles\Tests.dat'
    WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\DataFiles\FormatFiles\TestFormat.Fmt');
GO
```

Tests.dat contains:

```
b00d23fe-580e-42dc-abd4-e8a054395126,48dd5dd6e3a144f7a817f234dd51469c,452eb8ce-6ae2-4e7a-a389-1097882c83ab,,, ,,,,Aria,,,160,,,86400,,2004-04-03 23:23:00.000,,2012-07-06 13:26:31.633,2012-07-06 13:27:44.650,3,,,,51B7A831-4731-4E2E-ACEC-06636ADC7AD3,,0,,0,,Field Name 1,,Field Name 2,,Field Name 3,,Field Name 4,
```

and the format file TestFormat.fmt contains:

```
9.0
39
1       SQLCHAR       0       37      ","      1     Key                                              ""
2       SQLCHAR       0       37      ","      2     TestType                                         ""
3       SQLCHAR       0       37      ","      3     CaseKey                                          ""
4       SQLCHAR       0       30      ","      4     Height                                           ""
5       SQLCHAR       0       30      ","      5     Weight                                           ""
6       SQLCHAR       0       128     ","      6     PacemakerType                                    Latin1_General_CI_AI
7       SQLCHAR       0       0       ","      7     Diary                                            Latin1_General_CI_AI
8       SQLCHAR       0       0       ","      8     Indication                                       Latin1_General_CI_AI
9       SQLCHAR       0       0       ","      9     Medication                                       Latin1_General_CI_AI
10      SQLCHAR       0       37      ","      10    RecorderType                                     ""
11      SQLCHAR       0       100     ","      11    RecorderSerial                                   Latin1_General_CI_AI
12      SQLCHAR       0       0       ","      12    Comments                                         Latin1_General_CI_AI
13      SQLCHAR       0       12      ","      13    Status                                           ""
14      SQLCHAR       0       0       ","      14    AdditionalData                                   Latin1_General_CI_AI
15      SQLCHAR       0       37      ","      15    OrderKey                                         ""
16      SQLCHAR       0       12      ","      16    Duration                                         ""
17      SQLCHAR       0       12      ","      17    Age                                              ""
18      SQLCHAR       0       24      ","      18    RecordingStartDateTime                           ""
19      SQLCHAR       0       128     ","      19    Ward                                             Latin1_General_CI_AI
20      SQLCHAR       0       24      ","      20    CreatedDateTime                                  ""
21      SQLCHAR       0       24      ","      21    UpdatedDateTime                                  ""
22      SQLCHAR       0       21      ","      22    UserGroupBits                                    ""
23      SQLCHAR       0       24      ","      23    LastArchive                                      ""
24      SQLCHAR       0       128     ","      24    PointOfCare                                      Latin1_General_CI_AI
25      SQLCHAR       0       128     ","      25    Bed                                              Latin1_General_CI_AI
26      SQLCHAR       0       37      ","      26    DownloadFacilityKey                              ""
27      SQLCHAR       0       37      ","      27    AnalysisFacilityKey                              ""
28      SQLCHAR       0       12      ","      28    Priority                                         ""
29      SQLCHAR       0       37      ","      29    FacilityKey                                      ""
30      SQLCHAR       0       12      ","      30    PacemakerTypeStandard                            ""
31      SQLCHAR       0       128     ","      31    TestTypeName                                     Latin1_General_CI_AI
32      SQLCHAR       0       128     ","      32    UserDefined1Name                                 Latin1_General_CI_AI
33      SQLCHAR       0       128     ","      33    UserDefined1Value                                Latin1_General_CI_AI
34      SQLCHAR       0       128     ","      34    UserDefined2Name                                 Latin1_General_CI_AI
35      SQLCHAR       0       128     ","      35    UserDefined2Value                                Latin1_General_CI_AI
36      SQLCHAR       0       128     ","      36    UserDefined3Name                                 Latin1_General_CI_AI
37      SQLCHAR       0       128     ","      37    UserDefined3Value                                Latin1_General_CI_AI
38      SQLCHAR       0       128     ","      38    UserDefined4Name                                 Latin1_General_CI_AI
39      SQLCHAR       0       128     "\r\n"   39    UserDefined4Value                                Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

I cannot figure out why this isn't working. Other people have had similar problems because they had more fields and actual columns in their database. Or using .csv files which are not supported apparently.

This works fine on every other table in the database I am importing with no errors so I can't understand why it doesn't work here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: do you have this in the SP? "SET NOCOUNT ON"

Comment: That would just stop it from displaying the message.